# Need to fetch only the required part

Tags: shell, sed, grep, cut

We have a string as below:

```
**XX_EMAIL_FILES FCP_REQID=9614696 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/sup12" FCP_USERID=5667 FCP_USERNAME="SRI" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 "9614556_SUP12_XX_Workflow_Stuck_AP_Invoices.csv" "/tmp_mnt2/attachments" "Sri.B@xx.com" "This is the subject for the mail" "PFA for the list of Invoices that are stuck in workflow."**
```

We need to fetch only the below string into a variable:

*This is the subject for the mail*

Similarly, need to fetch only the below string into other variable:
*PFA for the list of Invoices that are stuck in workflow.*

These are not always the same. the strings may vary based on what user entered.

Can anyone please help me on how to fetch only those strings using UNIX commands

Regards,
Bommi

Comment: is the format consistent across all data?

Comment: format is consistent. But, some times it is like *This is the subject for the mail*, sometimes it may like *This is the subject for the mail. With more subject* and sometimes it is just NULL value

Comment: To make things more readable, I'd suggest you to [format as code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) any text that has to be fed as input/matched literally/read by a program. It will help avoiding ambiguities, e.g. are flanking `**` part of the original string?

Comment: Use e.g. `sed(1)` to isolate the required substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sure about number and order of fields and quotes in them, then you could use `cut -d\"` to get required fields like this:

```
echo 'XX_EMAIL_FILES FCP_REQID=9614696 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/sup12" FCP_USERID=5667 FCP_USERNAME="SRI" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 "9614556_SUP12_XX_Workflow_Stuck_AP_Invoices.csv" "/tmp_mnt2/attachments" "Sri.B@xx.com" "This is the subject for the mail" "PFA for the list of Invoices that are stuck in workflow."' \
| cut -f14 -d\"
This is the subject for the mail

echo 'XX_EMAIL_FILES FCP_REQID=9614696 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/sup12" FCP_USERID=5667 FCP_USERNAME="SRI" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 "9614556_SUP12_XX_Workflow_Stuck_AP_Invoices.csv" "/tmp_mnt2/attachments" "Sri.B@xx.com" "This is the subject for the mail" "PFA for the list of Invoices that are stuck in workflow."' \
| cut -f16 -d\"
PFA for the list of Invoices that are stuck in workflow.
```

Or may be even better to use `awk` if you need to get last two fields:

```
echo 'XX_EMAIL_FILES FCP_REQID=9614696 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/sup12" FCP_USERID=5667 FCP_USERNAME="SRI" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 "9614556_SUP12_XX_Workflow_Stuck_AP_Invoices.csv" "/tmp_mnt2/attachments" "Sri.B@xx.com" "This is the subject for the mail" "PFA for the list of Invoices that are stuck in workflow."' \
| awk -F\" '{ print $(NF-3) }'
This is the subject for the mail
```

Comment: I used cut -f14 -d\". It is ok. But now facing an other issue

Actually, we developed host file (using UNIX) to send emails. Here, user provide the subject and body while running the programs (Oracle Concurrent Programs).

After fetching the subject and body values using above commands, the values are stores in variables as below:

FCP_SUBJECT as *This is the subject*
and
FCP_BODY as *This is the body*

Now, mailing as below:
*
echo "Hello,

${FCP_BODY}

Thanks,
${FCP_USERNAME}

"| mailx -s$FCP_SUBJECT
*

Then, the mail subject is coming as just *This*

Comment: @Bommi, that is a different question from what you asked above .... post a new question

Comment: @Bommi If you run `mailx -s$FCP_SUBJECT`, the variable `FCP_SUBJECT` undergoes splitting and its first word only is used as the argument value to `-s`. Pay attention to [quoting your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/315749).